# How do I pass URLs from A's method to B's by changing code of yield SplashRequest?? (Scrapy + Splash with Python & Dcoker)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-splash

########### This article is posted before I found it using scrapy + splash is not best way because I checked rendered pages (http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=xxx) has no data I want. That's why I try another way to make use of selenium or something. Thank you!!

【What I Want to Know: How do I should modify code of yield SplashRequest(url, callback=self.parse, args = {"wait": 5}, endpoint = "render.html")】

I don't have no idea that I should change code in order to pass URLs from A's method to B's in case of using scrapy + splash.

In my opinion, the corrected places are,

yield SplashRequest(url, callback=self.parse, args = {"wait": 5}, endpoint = "render.html")

of start_requests method(#1).

There are 3 reasons.

## 1st reason is,

logging.info(#2) before of "yield SplashRequest(url, callback=self.parse, args = {"wait": 5}, endpoint = "render.html")" gave me correct feedback.

## 2nd reason is,

I set up scrapy + splash, reading Scrapy+Splash's README of as reference.

Scrapy+Splash for JavaScript integration
https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash

## 3rd reason is,

logging method(#3) gave me NO information.
Here is my code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from bnb_sentiment.items import BnbItem
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
import re
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# __name__ is name of a method
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class BnbPriceTestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bnb_price_test'

    start_urls = [

        # Tokyo--Japan
        'https://www.airbnb.com/s/Tokyo--Japan/homes?refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&allow_override%5B%5D=&checkin=2018-07-07&checkout=2018-07-08&locale=en&min_beds=0&price_max=20000&price_min=10000&query=Tokyo%2C%20Japan&place_id=ChIJ51cu8IcbXWARiRtXIothAS4&s_tag=Mz88jJs1',    

    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            logger.info(url) #2
            yield SplashRequest(url, callback=self.parse, args = {"wait": 5}, endpoint = "render.html") #1

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//div[contains(@id, "listing-")]//a[contains(@href, "rooms")]/@href'):
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            logger.info(href)
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            logger.info(url) #3
            yield SplashRequest(url, callback=self.parse_scrape)

    def parse_scrape(self, response):
         pass
```

(#2) Here is the feedback of logging method.

> /home/ubuntu/bnbsp/bnb_sentiment/bnb_sentiment/spiders/bnb_price.py(34)start_requests()
>   -> logger.info(url) *1
>   (Pdb) url
>   'url is same as start_urls'

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @parik Thank you for your quick comment. My question is "how I pass URLs from A's method to B's by changing code of yield SplashRequest (Scrapy + Splash with Python & Dcoker).

Comment: I found it using scrapy + splash is not best way because I checked rendered pages (http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=xxx) has no data I want. That's why I try another way to make use of selenium or something. Thank you!!